# Flash AS3 Global Security Settings - programmatically

Tags: xml, security, actionscript-3, flash

In my application I am accessing a XML file which is in the same location as the fla,  yet I have to add my folder location to the Flash Global security settings in order to avoid that infamous Security violation that is thrown. Thats fine in my development environment, however when deployed on a customer's machine they have the same issue. Is there a way programmatically to to trust the xml file and avoid the security violation? NOTE the customer is accessing the swf in 2 ways through a .NET loading mechanism and 2. opening the file location in a web browser (NOT in a we page but opening the swf directly - YES I know this is not recommended - but nevertheless is the customer's preference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can do.

1) You can make your SWF an AIR app, which doesn't have the same security requirements as simple SWFs.

2) If you don't need to access the XML outside of the SWf, consider using the `SharedObject` class - you don't need to change anything in your code; just save the XML object inside the SharedObject. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

3) If the XML isn't changing, then you can directly embed it in the SWF ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ffb.html ). This will avoid everything and enable you to access the XML directly without needing to load it.

Comment: divilysausages, thanks for the tip . I actually did embed my xml and css I was loading at runtime and those errors went away. Now I'm running into another non descript security message:   "SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context."   Any ideas on that one?

Comment: what are you trying to load when you get that error? Is it when you load, or when you try to access what you load? Take a look at the `LoaderContext` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html. It could also be an incorrect path name somewhere - try http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=409 as well to see if it helps

Comment: See, That's the problem I don't know whats loading, it doesn't happen in my environment but in the test environment where I'm accessing the swf via a file server. Thx I will check out those links...

Comment: I did separate my LoaderContext() and URLRequest calls, I thought maybe it was that known timing issue, but that did not work either.

Comment: does is work in the browser, just not in the .NET environment, or is it not working in both? Is the data coming from the same server, or an external one? If it's coming from an external one, you'll need to make sure there's a crossdomain.xml file there. Check out the `Security` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html, it might help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use crossdomain.xml on the server?